# ListContourPlot not plotting all data points

Tags: plotting

I have been using Mathematica for quite a while but am really stuck with this problem for too long now and appreciate any help. Thanks a lot.

I am using `ListContourPlot` to plot a list with each element of format `{r,t,z}`. The results of `ListContourPlot` do not display all data. However, when I select a particular value of t and use `ListPlot`, I do see the expected values. Can someone tell me why `ListContourPlot` is not showing the right contours?

I am using the following commands for plotting

```
ListContourPlot[data, PlotLegends -> Automatic, Epilog -> {Point@data[[All, {1, 2}]]}]

ListLinePlot[{Transpose[{Select[data, #[[2]] == .01 &][[All, 1]], 
Select[data, #[[2]] == .01 &][[All, 3]]}]}]
```

yielding

[image: Mathematica graphics]

and

[image: Mathematica graphics]

As you can see, there are in fact data points in the empty areas of the `ListContourPlot`.
Also, notice in the list plot corresponding to `t=0.01`, `z` should be less than `0.2` for `r>2*10^-8`, but the contour plot gives a much higher value.

The data is available at https://pastebin.com/raw/uyLvUcb3

```
data = Get["https://pastebin.com/raw/uyLvUcb3"];
```